# Laravel 8 Validation - Require either field but not both

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

I have two boolean fields on a form: incident_sd and incident_snr.
I want the validation logic to check to ensure:

- **Either** can be 1 (true), but **not** both equal 1
- The other field should then be 0 (false)

I'd appreciate some help please!

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: This seems like the use case for a radio button set. But I know that doesn't aswer the question. Is there any reason you didn't choose it?

Answer (score -1):

did you try this validation method "different"??? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-different

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'incident_sd' => 'required|boolean|different:incident_snr',
        'incident_snr' => 'required|boolean|different:incident_sd',
    ]);

    // The blog post is valid...
}
```

this is thinking in both values are required at the moment of submit

Comment: the correct rule is "required_without:other_field"